# Запретить подчёркивание и дефис в начале строки

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте, есть регулярка `~^[a-zA-Z_0-9-]*$~` которую я с трудом набросал, так как плохо разбираюсь в них. Не подскажите как можно её изменить, чтобы текст не мог начинаться с символов `_` и `-` ?

Comment: `~^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z_0-9-]*$~`

Comment: У вас текст может быть пустым?

Comment: @Visman нет, это ник. К примеру user_-123

Comment: @Владимир, тогда вариант от rjhdby вполне подойдет.

Comment: @rjhdby перенесите в ответ, поставлю галочку

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> чтобы текст не мог начинаться с символов `_` и `-` ?

Самый простой вариант - это просто выписать допустимые первые символы отдельно:

```
~^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z_0-9-]*$~
```

Обращаю внимание, что этой регулярке перестала соответствовать пустая строка. Если нужно разрешить пустую строку, то придётся на неё проверять отдельно:

```
~^([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z_0-9-]*)?$~
```

Ещё один минус данного подхода - если разрешённые символы вдруг изменятся, то придётся менять их в двух местах.

В общем, я рекомендую другой вариант, а именно запрещать конкретные первые символы:

```
~^(?![-_])[a-zA-Z_0-9-]*$~
```